# JS calling a function in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

I know how to send message from JS to native IOS swift app:

```
func userContentController(userContentController: WKUserContentController!, didReceiveScriptMessage message: WKScriptMessage!) {

        println("JavaScript is sending a message \(message.body)")

}
```

and JS:

```
webkit.messageHandlers.callbackHandler.postMessage("Hello from JavaScript");
```

My question: is it possible to directly call a function in the native app rather then receiving the message in my example code.

say i want in the JS to use something like:

```
webkit.messageHandlers.someFunctionName()
```

The reason i am asking is that In Android thats how it works

Comment: you have a url you use right? to call the js from the ios app?

Answer (score 3):

WKWebView supports only the raw message passing interface. You have to wrap it for complex interactions between JS and native.

I created a project named [XWebView](https://github.com/xwebview/xwebview) which offers language binding styled API based on the raw message passing of WKWebView. It's written in Swift.

For example, you can write a plugin in Swift:

```
class Plugin : NSObject {
    func someFunctionName() {
        doSomeThing()
    }
}
```

Expose an instance of the plugin to JavaScript before loading HTML:

```
let webView = WKWebView(frame: frame, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())
webView.loadPlugin(Plugin(), namespace: "foo")
```

Call the function from JavaScript:

```
window.foo.someFunctionName()
```

It's really easy and straightforward. For more details, please check the project's page.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to use URL query variables, like you would connect to PHP using Swift.

Here is an example of how to get query variables in Javascript: [Get url parameter jquery Or How to Get Query String Values In js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery)

Then when you run the Javascript you can check what the URL query variables are and then run a function based on that.

For example, we use the variable `command` below, to say what function to run:

```
example.com?command=foo
```

then do something like this in Javascript:

```
if(command == 'foo') {
   runFoo();
}
```

Then you could also use URL query variables to specify arguments for the function.

**If you choose PHP**

If you choose to use PHP, you can do the same thing with `$_GET['command'];`.