# How can I binding an object to JS when using the WKWebview

Tags: ios8, wkwebview

I met a problem.

I replaced uiwebview with WKwebview ,but how can I pass my OC Object to JS.

Can My object conform the JSContext protocol？

before

*-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [self.webView.scrollView.mj_header endRefreshing];*

```
_jsContext = [webView valueForKeyPath:@"documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext"];
_jsContext.exceptionHandler = ^(JSContext *context, JSValue *exceptionValue) {
    context.exception = exceptionValue;
    NSLog(@"%@", exceptionValue);
};

_jsContext[@"token"] = self.token;
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"getUser()"];
```

}

now how can I inject the Token to JS

Comment: please show your code

Comment: Getting JSContext is impossible in WKWebView. Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31024055/2186063) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32120375/2186063).